# SQL 2014 How do I pull data from events that happen on a single day?

Tags: sql, sql-server

SQL Server Express 2014--- Hello, I am very very new to SQL and making queries. Basically, I am looking to pull events that start and end on the same day.

*The Question being asked: "From the Engagements table, show all Engagements that started and stopped within the same day." Events that happened between a 24hr day.

I can't seem to write the proper syntax. My progress so far...

```
SELECT EngagementNumber,StartDate, StartTime, Stoptime, 
FROM Engagements
WHERE CAST(Stoptime-Starttime AS INTERGER)=1
```

Comment: This question does not give us nearly enough information to give a sensible answer. Please pretend that we know nothing about your needs and you have to explain your problem to a rubber duck. What would your question be under these conditions?

Comment: we will need to know which database you are using (oracle, MySQL, or whatever), as well as a sample of what is in your table(s).

Comment: What columns does your `Engagements` table contain, do you have any sample data to show us?

Answer (score -1):

When posting a SQL query question, its always best to give a sample of your data and some table information regarding fields.

What I have included below are a number of queries based off your original query that are all designed to display that dataset in slightly different ways.

On a side note. I am not sure why you have that Stoptime - Starttime in your where clause and have kept it. But I do hate having aggregates in a where clause. This is a personal choice thing but might be something to keep in mind, there are other clauses like "HAVING" that I generally use.

Below are the query sets, let me know if one of them suits your purpose and I can expand on them if needed.

```
---- Your original query (You had and extra , in there)
SELECT 
    EngagementNumber,
    StartDate, 
    StartTime, 
    Stoptime
FROM Engagements
WHERE 
    CAST(Stoptime-Starttime AS INTERGER)=1

---- This will Get all events on the day, take their stop and start then sum all of it together
---- This might not be what you want, its handy for counting how many events are on a day or
---- the total effect of a day, with a group by you must be working with aggregates
SELECT 
    StartDate, 
    COUNT(EngagementNumber) AS NumberofEvents,
    SUM(Stoptime-Starttime) AS TotalTimeTaken
FROM Engagements
WHERE 
    CAST(Stoptime-Starttime AS INTERGER)=1
GROUP BY
    StartDate

---- This will pull all the values and sort them by date
---- It will give you a line for every Engagement but list all the 01/01 and then 02/01
SELECT 
    EngagementNumber,
    StartDate, 
    StartTime, 
    Stoptime
FROM Engagements
WHERE 
    CAST(Stoptime-Starttime AS INTERGER)=1
ORDER BY 
    StartDate

---- This includes a Date parameter in the where clause to allow you to bring
---- back a single day of engagements.
SELECT 
    EngagementNumber,
    StartDate, 
    StartTime, 
    Stoptime
FROM Engagements
WHERE 
    CAST(Stoptime-Starttime AS INTERGER)=1
    AND StartDate = ?
```

Comment: How is this an answer? Rather then guessing wildly, ask the OP for further information so you can ask the question properly.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson calm down, this is not guessing widely. The question has been posed requesting a listing of engagements surrounding a date. The only thing in question is exactly what output was expecting. So it seems an easy leap so give a number of date specific manipulations of the data. This provides an answer to the possible date specific data sets. Friendliness is a good attribute on here.

Comment: I am calm, don’t worry about me. I still think that this is not a viable answer, take your inclusion of the `where` clause for instance that you admit yourself that you you don’t understand, how can that possibly filter out events from different days?

Comment: I am 90% sure that clause is to capture events that a duration greater than 1 minute - I guess there are events that have a 0 duration which are not reportable

Comment: It uses `=` not `>`

Comment: Very true, not sure then.